# select input type text values inside a div using domXpath

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

i am trying access values of textbox which is inside DIV using domXpath.

basically, i have multiple DIVs and each DIV contains some input type text and it has some values in it.

i want to create an array and map it with its parent DIV

my sample HTML code:

```
<div class="div_common_class">
    <div class="content_area">
        <div class="field_name">this is first</div>
    </div>

    <div class="input_area">
        <input type="text" name="" value="111" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div_common_class">
    <div class="content_area">
        <div class="field_name">this is second</div>
    </div>

    <div class="input_area">
        <input type="text" name="" value="222" />
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "div_common_class")]');
```

from the above PHP code i only get the values of the DIV, but not getting values of input type text.

and output something like:

**this is first 111**

**this is second 222**

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath gets the right divs, but you still need to get the values.

You could use `getElementsByTagName` and use a `foreach` or get the elements by `item` like this example:

```
$results = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "div_common_class")]');
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo sprintf("<b>%s %s</b><br>",
        $result->getElementsByTagName("div")->item(1)->textContent,
        $result->getElementsByTagName("input")->item(0)->getAttribute("value"));
}
```

That would give you:

> **this is first 111**
>
> **this is second 222**

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/Dh0uH)